# Laravel - Guardar un registro en BD

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, model

Tengo una migración de clientes donde se guardan algunos registros para hacer pruebas.

```
<?php

use App\Models\Cliente;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Clientes extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('clientes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->string('nombre', 191);
            $table->string('email', 191)->unique()->nullable();
            $table->string('password', 191);
            $table->boolean('vip')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('activo')->default(1);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        // Seed some clients
        $this->seedClientsForTests();
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('clientes');
    }


    private function seedClientsForTests()
    {
        $out = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput();
        $out->writeln("Seeding clients...");

        $cliente = new Cliente;
        $cliente->nombre      = 'coco';
        $cliente->apellidos   = 'fake';
        $cliente->email       = 'coco@mail.com';
        $cliente->password    = bcrypt('123456');
        $cliente->vip         = 1;
        $cliente->save();

        Cliente::create([
            'nombre'      => 'foo',
            'apellidos'   => 'li',
            'email'       => 'foo@mail.com',
            'password'    => bcrypt('123456'),
            'vip'         => 1,
        ]);

        Cliente::create([
            'nombre'      => 'xxx',
            'apellidos'   => '',
            'email'       => 'xxx@mail.com',
            'password'    => bcrypt('123456'),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Y el modelo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Cliente extends Authenticatable
{

    protected $table    = 'clientes';
    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre',
        'apellido',
        'email',
        'password',
        'activo',
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token'
    ];
}
```

Cuando guardo los clientes hay hay una diferencia importante según el método empleado.

1. Cuando *instancio* un cliente y le asignó cada propiedad antes de guardarlo (cliente 'coco' en el código) se almacena correctamente.
2. Cuando uso el método estático `Cliente::create()` el cliente se crea, pero la propiedad 'vip' toma el valor por defecto asignado en la migración, es decir 0, aunque le esté indicando que su valor es 1. Esto se soluciona si se añade a la lista `fillable` del modelo el campo 'vip'.

¿Porque estas diferencias entre el método 1 y 2 de almacenar un registro y cual es más recomendable usar dado que `$fillable` se usa por temas de seguridad?

Comment: ¿Por que creas un `seed` dentro de la migración? ¿No seria mejor utilizar un `seeder` aparte? el comando es `php artisan make:seeder <seeder_name>`

Comment: En mi caso utilizo `create()` y `update()` por cuestiones de seguridad, solamente cuando voy a eliminar lógicamente utilizo `save()` ya que en este ultimo te puedes saltar el `filliable`.

Comment: @anayarojo normalmente uso *seeders*. Estoy trabajando con un código heredado extrayendo una parte del sistema para integrarlo en una instalación limpia y hacer unas pruebas, estoy en fase de sacar los ficheros mínimos necesarios. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las diferencias entre `save()` y `create()` son varias, voy a listar las más relevantes:

1. Finalidad:

   - `save()` se usa para crear o actualizar modelos.
   - `create()` se usa exclusivamente para crear modelos.
2. Parámetros de entrada:

   - `save()` se aplica a una instancia del modelo.
   - `create()` acepta un array de atributos.
3. save() ocurre en ambos casos:

   - El proceso de `create()` incluye a `save()` al final del proceso de «creación», así que finalmente, si usas `create()` o `save()`, de una u otra forma pasarás por `save()`.
4. Descripción rápida de los procesos:

   - `create()` utiliza el método `fill()` antes de llegar a `save()`, el cual revisa los atributos que estén protegidos en la propiedad `guarded` y los que están en `fillable`. `create()` También realiza algunos otros procesos con los traits (que podrían ser incluso modificados) y algún evento adicional.
   - `save()` no pasa por el método `fill()`, va directamente al query builder para conectarse con la base de datos y guardar.

---

En cuanto a buenas prácticas en Laravel, no es mejor ni más recomendable usar `save()` o `create()`, la diferencia ya la conoces en cuanto a la seguridad/protección de los atributos, personalmente prefiero `create()`, por los siguientes motivos:

- Acepta un array, es una estructura más simple.
- Solo se necesita una línea de código (independiente que visualmente el array lo dividas en una línea por cada $key => 'value').
- Considero más semántico el nombre y la sintaxis de `create()`.
- Me obliga a mantener limpias/actualizadas/correctas mis propiedades `guarded` y `fillable` en el modelo.
- Me gusta la «capa» adicional de seguridad que ofrece con las propiedad mencionadas arriba.

---

Por último, algo de código de referencia:

Método save() en Database/Eloquent/Model.php

```
/**
 * Save the model to the database.
 *
 * @param  array  $options
 * @return bool
 */
public function save(array $options = [])
{
    $query = $this->newModelQuery();

    // If the "saving" event returns false we'll bail out of the save and return
    // false, indicating that the save failed. This provides a chance for any
    // listeners to cancel save operations if validations fail or whatever.
    if ($this->fireModelEvent('saving') === false) {
        return false;
    }

    // If the model already exists in the database we can just update our record
    // that is already in this database using the current IDs in this "where"
    // clause to only update this model. Otherwise, we'll just insert them.
    if ($this->exists) {
        $saved = $this->isDirty() ?
                    $this->performUpdate($query) : true;
    }

    // If the model is brand new, we'll insert it into our database and set the
    // ID attribute on the model to the value of the newly inserted row's ID
    // which is typically an auto-increment value managed by the database.
    else {
        $saved = $this->performInsert($query);

        if (! $this->getConnectionName() &&
            $connection = $query->getConnection()) {
            $this->setConnection($connection->getName());
        }
    }

    // If the model is successfully saved, we need to do a few more things once
    // that is done. We will call the "saved" method here to run any actions
    // we need to happen after a model gets successfully saved right here.
    if ($saved) {
        $this->finishSave($options);
    }

    return $saved;
}
```

Método create() en Database/Eloquent/Builder, **se puede ver que una vez se crea el modelo, pasa esa instancia al método save()**

```
/**
 * Save a new model and return the instance.
 *
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|$this
 */
public function create(array $attributes = [])
{
    return tap($this->newModelInstance($attributes), function ($instance) {
        $instance->save();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ambas funcionan bien, lo que pasa es que el campo `vip` no esta en el `fillable` por eso al ser `null`, toma el valor por defecto asignado en la `Base de Datos` en este caso el `0` (supongo que es `INTEGER`)

```
protected $fillable = [
    'nombre',
    'apellido',
    'email',
    'password',
    'activo',
];
```

Tendrías que aumentar el `'activo'` a `'vip'`